# Problems With Creating an instance of outlook application, on a server

Tags: office-interop

i have a console app in c#, which needs to open an outlook session.
when i put it on the server it faild, and it doesn't even throw expetion when the following code done:

```
Outlook.Application app=new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
```

only when the outlook  is open on the sever the code is working , because the  app is set to:

```
app = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
```

is there somthing to do about it?
because i need the outlook to be close

Answer (score 0):

Dania,

Do you have Outlook installed on the server?

Anyway, **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Comment: i have outlook 2010 installed on my server. and it use to 2013 exchange